# How to save only the first and second line first line of a variable that contains multiple lines?

Tags: python

My goal is to use Python to save Only the first and second line of the variable `temp_data` (that contains multiple lines).  Each line should be saved as one variable. So I can display the high temperature on my Raspberry Pi LCD.

For example, `temp_data` has info (each number is on one line, stack overflow doesn't display properly):

```
60
54
57
56
59
57
59
61
60
60
```

code below:

```
from weather import Weather, Unit

weather = Weather(unit=Unit.FAHRENHEIT)

location = weather.lookup_by_location('Dublin')
forecasts = location.forecast
for forecast in forecasts:
    temp_data = forecast.high
    print(temp_data)
```

Resolved: This is how it should be done:

```
from weather import Weather, Unit

weather = Weather(unit=Unit.FAHRENHEIT)

location = weather.lookup_by_location('cupertino')
forecasts = location.forecast

line_num = 0

for forecast in forecasts:
    temp_data = forecast.high
    if (line_num == 1):
        print(temp_data)
    line_num = line_num+1
```

Comment: I have displayed it properly, no issue about stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I assume by the 'first and second' lines you're after the maximum and minimum high temperatures from the list. This line can replace your for loop to find the temperatures:

```
highest = max(forecast.high for forecast in forecasts)
lowest = min(forecast.high for forecast in forecasts)
```

The `max` and `min` functions are built-in to Python. The parameter to those functions is called a list comprehension.

If you genuinely want the first and second lines, the list comprehension with some unpacking makes quite a nice line:

```
first, second = [forecast.high for forecast in forecasts[:2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `max` + `map`:

```
max(map(lambda i: i.high,forecasts))
```

And if want minumum `min` + `map`:

```
min(map(lambda i: i.high,forecasts))
```

If want to sort:

```
sorted(map(lambda i: i.high,forecasts))
```